# Android change DayNight mode at runtime

Tags: android, android-theme

I am using the DayNight mode API on Android. I have this settings checkbox that can toggle between Day and Night Mode. I call recreate() on my Settings Activity when the toggle changes and I send an event to my Main Activity to recreate itself. Everything works fine but recreating the Main Activity takes an enormous amount of time (From calling recreate() to the it actually coming to the onCreate() method). Close to ~10 seconds. I'm sure there is a faster way to do it but I just don't know how. The Twitter app is pretty instantaneous in this regard. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

PS: I save and restore my data from a Parcelable Array List as well so I'm not sure why it takes so long to get there

Comment: if you have solution please, post it. I also searching it

Comment: I use the same approach and recreate() works instantly. Could you check LogCat to see what takes so long time?